# Fetching last twelve months records based on today's date in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 database. I want to pull all the records of last twelve months from a table based on today's date. I am trying with following query. But it's not fetching the eligible records.

```
SELECT * FROM PQCUSTSRV where CALLERKEY='2020-07-13-06.14.29.163600' 
      AND CRDATTIM BETWEEN  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 12 month);
```

Here the column `CRDATTIM` is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not in DB2 but some db need  BETWEEN with lower  value first

```
SELECT * 
FROM PQCUSTSRV 
where CALLERKEY='2020-07-13-06.14.29.163600' 
AND CRDATTIM BETWEEN (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 12 month) AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT * FROM PQCUSTSRV where CALLERKEY='2020-07-13-06.14.29.163600' 
      AND CRDATTIM>=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 12 month) and CRDATTIM<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Perfect!!..+1 for quick response.